# ubuntu 14.04 maas doesn't auto detect ipmi

Tags: 14.04, maas, ipmi

I have recently upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. When I pxe boot the nodes I get the message that the node has no power type set so I can't commission it. I have tried manually setting the IPMI option however the nodes won't boot. This works fine on maas installation from ubuntu 12.04 CD.

My nodes are all Dell servers.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ I don't think that PXE installations are that much popular with Ubuntu desktop users.

Comment: has anyone else tried IPMI with MAAS 1.5?

Comment: This isn't for desktop use. I am using MAAS to add server nodes for JUJU.

Comment: that's why I was suggesting a server oriented, or unix oriented forum. Anyway, I think that you will be fine with the pdf linked in one of the comments at this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/396799/howto-configure-maas-to-separate-pxe-traffic-and-ipmi-traffic-on-different-subne

Comment: MAAS has gone through a few revisions since 12.04, the version shipping with Trusty is 1.5. There have been a few changes to the Power management, with additional methods added and more support for different protocols. Which version of IPMI are you using? 1.5 or 2.0? Make sure the protocol is set to the right one in the Node edit screen

Comment: with 1.5 the power type is blank so I have to manually assign the power type. With 1.4 the same node is set to autodetect, the IP address, maas as username and some random generated password. I have tried putting the same settings in 1.5 with both 2.0 and 1.5 and neither one works. I even installed ipmitool on the regional controller and tried from command line and I get lan errors.

Comment: I saw this bug reported but I am not sure if they are related. https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1308070